# How to set a permission for each user request in c# web services

Tags: c#, web-services

currently i am working on DMS project in which user can save and retrieve documents. 
now i want to set a permission for each user at service level. now i am able to catch each user request in which i got the link of the request,user name and his roll,userid. suppose i have a three roles one is admin which has all permissions and second roll is supervisor.so supervisor can create a user and assign department to assign a department it uses i.e item/assigndepartment. and third roll is clerk i want to restrict to create a user but he can access the department list on department section not in user. to display department list i am using the same request link i.e item/assigndepartment.  so how to handle this situation. :(

is it good to store the each roll specific link into table and then check for each request ???

here is my structure.

```
 public class IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, 
  IAuthenticationFilter
     {
          public string Realm { get; set; }

         public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;

        if (context.Request.RequestUri.LocalPath == "/Login/UserLogin")
        {
            return; 
        }
        // here i am catching the each request from which i am getting the user name,roll and user id.

     }
 }
```

and the controller

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
     //item/assigndepartment
    [HttpPost]
    public CategoryList assigndepartment(Departments dept)
    {
        catList = _itemsModel.assigndepartment(dept);
        return catList;
    }

}
```

and model

```
  public class ItemModel
     {

    publiv void assigndepartment()
       { 

        \\ DB Logic

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building RESTful API, you should have GET and POST methods to item/assigndepartment. Than you can restrict both actions in the controller to their respective roles.

If you are building web app, you can create partial views or view components and render each component depending on the user role.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply. i am building RESTful API. is their only way to store the link for respective roles in database? and then check the respective link has permission for that particular role ? any other way ?

Comment: No, the correct way to handle this is using ASP.NET Identity. You can use the "Authorize" filter with Roles parameter to restrict the access to only particular roles.
Check this article [here](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/).

Comment: in my application i have a multiple features like user in which we cant create a user and department where we can create a department. in user feature i am restricting supervisor to create a user(in user feature we can assign department using user/ALLdepartmentList link so i am restricting supervisor for this link ) but supervisor can access the department feature in which he can see the department to show department i am using the same link user/ALLdepartmentList the same link which is used in user so i want to give permission for the supervisor for the same link to see department list